# Chromecast user agent

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

Is it possible to change the user agent the chromecast sends to servers?

I am trying to load a mobile video and the server requires that the user agent be from a mobile device.

Thanks.

Comment: As your chromecast is going to download the video for you (not the mobile) and display it on a TV or a larger screen than a mobile I don't recommand you to use a mobile video but the best resolution you can offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot change the user agent

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: The user is asking if the user agent can be changed and I am answering that it cannot be. So that is an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's a good question, but I'm afraid you won't be able.
Anyway, you can play with the [host method to change/send custom headers](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/player), so maybe you can figure out how to send the request to simulate a mobile device into your servers.

Also, be careful with the media you want to play in Chromecast, there's a [list of supported formats](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/media) and the recommendation is to follow that "rule".